# C# Wait without making the thread sleep and freezing the program.

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

Please suggest a way or a function to make the code wait for a couple of seconds before proceeding. I know about the thread.sleep method but it freezes the entire program.

I would like to place in a short pause for the program to do its procedure before resuming with the next part. At the moment the program performs all of its procedures too quickly for other procedures to follow.

Here is my code:

```
     {
        w1.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib").InnerText = "some text";
        w1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");

      //Some code here that would create a 1 second pause before downloading html. 
      //Thread.sleep(2000) is not suitable. 

        string html = new WebClient().DownloadString(w1.Url.ToString());
```

Comment: You could use `async` programming pattern for that, in the case, you could write `await Task.Delay(2000);` and be done with it. However, best if you learn the pattern all over, and not just that waiting part.

Comment: Don't do `new WebClient().DownloadString(w1.Url.ToString())` - `WebClient` is disposable and needs to be disposed after use. If you chain like this you can create a memory leak.

Comment: *At the moment the program performs all of its procedures too quickly for other procedures to follow.* That sounds like a design smell. You shouldn't sleep just to make other components catch up. Perhaps describing what you're trying to achieve will help us understand how to help you.

Comment: I would way download your things in a different thread. During the download you could show progress bar or do something else.

Comment: Can you define the difference between 'Wait' and 'Freezing' ?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and suggestions, @AgentFire Your solution worked for me, thanks

Comment: @Dilshod Putting the method into another thread is a good idea but because of the hackish design of my program I wasn't able to get that to work but thanks for the idea

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yeah the design of the program could definitely be better and I wouldn't need a random pause between the procedures, you are correct.

Comment: @Henk Holterman When I used the Thread.Sleep(ms) command the entire UI became unresponsive for me and it seemed to that the program just froze. Where I used "Await Task.Delay(ms)" line of code the program paused, the previous methods caught up and the next methods resumed which is what I wanted.

Comment: @Enigmativity I didnt manage to figure out how to use the dispose method for the webclient, I understand how it works where I would use it for the StreamWritter to prevent memory leaks like you said, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @d12 - Try `string result; using (var wc = new WebClient()) { result = wc.DownloadString(...) }`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use `BackgroundWorker` for download, and in this thread you would use `Sleep` function before downloading.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing `W1` is a WebBrowser control.  Instead of submitting the form and sleeping, use the events exposed by the control to know that the document is ready.

You can use the `DocumentCompleted` event to know that the WebBrowser is done loading and you can then access the DOM for the new URL.

If you navigate multiple times you just need to keep some state around to know where you are in the process.